# What is the difference between pub/static/ vs /var/view_preprocessed/pub/static files and what should be right permission?

Tags: php, magento, file-permissions, magento2.4.4

Magento 2.4.4 served files from `pub/static/` directory and `/var/view_preprocessed/pub/static` directory but what is the difference in both path and what will be the idle permission in both cases.